# Paint problem when handling WM_CTLCOLOREDIT

Tags: winapi, paint, editcontrol

I have an non read only edit control for which I need to change colors so I handle WM_CTLCOLOREDIT. It works well when I am typing continuously but the problem is when I hit backspace or delete or even start typing from the middle of an existing text, the display is all junked up. That remains untill I cause a repaint by resizing the parent etc. How to fix this?

Edit: Some detail. The problem seems only when the background color is set and not when just the text color is set. The code looks like this

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_CTLCOLOREDIT, OnEditColor)

LRESULT CMyWindow::OnEditColor(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wp;
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)lp;
    if(hwnd == m_edit.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
    //  SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        MyControlInfo*pcti;// accessed from somewhere
        SetTextColor(hdc, pcti->theme.clrText);
    //  return (LRESULT)pcti->brush.GetSafeHandle();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: hard to tell without knowing what you are doing

Comment: @David Would the details I've update help?

Comment: I don't see any painting going on.

Comment: Aren't we just supposed to return the brush? Won't the system do the painting? I thought we paint ourselves only in ownerdrawn controls.

Comment: return 0 is going to lead to no painting

Comment: Oh, but even when I return a brush, the backspace delete etc won't paint properly. I tried returning a brush always. Anyway, since I have just one edit control, the zero return mustn't affect.

Answer (score 1):

I rather doubt that this is caused by this code.  It is the kind of problem you get when you try to subclass the edit control and override painting.  Windows version 2 having to run on a 386SUX and 20 years of appcompat prevented Microsoft from fixing this control so it only draws itself in the WM_PAINT message handler.  It indeed draws directly to the screen when you backspace.  There's no workaround for it.

Same comment applies as in your previous question, use a real edit control.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a background color with SetBkColor (And don't use SetBkMode) **and** return a valid brush. (You don't know how the control does its painting, it is free to use ExtTextOut with ETO_OPAQUE etc)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761691(v=vs.85).aspx

> Return Value
>
> If an application processes this
>   message, it must return the handle of
>   a brush. The system uses the brush to
>   paint the background of the edit
>   control.

So try something like:

```
return static_cast<LRESULT>(::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
```